# How would I go with calling a function when changing inventory items

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, so the problem is the following...

I'm trying to make some kind of "invsee" plugin and I want to refresh the inventory every time the inventory has changed.

All I've tried 'till this point is `InventoryClickEvent` and `InventoryInteractionEvent`.

That's where I have a problem. `InventoryClickEvent` only updates after the player click again after moving the item for me to refresh it.

For example, when a player picks up an item, I don't see it gone, unless he places it back down. When he does, I don't see it until he picks up another item, which I don't see it disappear unless he places it back down. ETC!

I want it to be "realtime" and I don't want to use `Scheduler`, because I've already tried that, but when I do that, screen flashes.

Thanks for the help, if you need parts of code or something just say.

MGlolenstine

Comment: It wouldn't help, Because the problem was, that the event was making me problems not anything else... I used the event, to draw target's inventory in a virtual inventory, but it didn't work... Ah well... Thanks to Frelling's answer I made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you intend to perform more complex actions other than looking at and possibly manipulating a player's inventory you can simplify this task. Given two `Player` objects `admin` and `target`, where `admin` needs to look at `target`'s inventory, you can view the inventory as follows:

```
Player admin = ...
Player target = ...
admin.openInventory( target.getInventory() );
```

This will allow you to view, add, remove, or change items in `target`'s inventory.

Comment: Well, hello... And I made a whole program to do that... :P didn't know that that was a thing... Thanks!

Comment: Ok, just another question... How would I check for items in offhand and in armour slots?